# Excel extract last digit from a string in order to do comparison with another key in value

Tags: excel

I had a set of string: SUF11080-302000R4, the R4 stand for revision 4.
I extract the revision no using formulae:
=RIGHT(B3,1) and put it in cell (D3)
Then i key in latest revision in cell (E3) in order to do comparison using 'if' function. But it doesn't work because the value extract using this formulae is only string not a numerical value, so cannot use to do compare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the double unary `--` to convert text that looks a number to a number:

```
=--RIGHT(B3, 1)
```

[image]